# What does $\sin x^2$ mean without any parenthesis?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My problem is to find the derivative of $y = (\cos 6x + \sin x^2)^{1/2}$

My textbook includes no parenthesis within the $\sin x^2$ term.

I am confused whether to interpret it as $\sin^2(x)$ or $\sin(x^2)$.

Comment: I'd guess it means $\sin(x^2)$, but it is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: I think they mean $\sin(x^2)$

Comment: I agree with the people who guess $\sin(x^2).$ Also, you didn't ask, but I'd guess that $\cos6x$ means $\cos(6x)$ and not $(\cos6)x.$

Comment: $\sin x^2=\sin (x^2)$, like $\cos 6x=\cos(6x)$. You may also write $\sin^2(x)=\sin^2 x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin x^2=\sin (x^2)$....and  $\sin^2x=(\sin x)^2.$ I suspect that the convention $f^nx=(f(x))^n,$ when f is one of the trig functions, arose when someone got tired of writing so many brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, $\sin x^2$ means $\sin(x^2)$, by the chain rule, you have
$$
\left(\sin(x^2) \right)'=2x \times \cos (x^2).
$$